# Shifting a String in C++ using functions

Tags: c++, console

Hello everyone I need your help here with this statement. I want to make a program that
takes a string and a number and returns a shifted, wrapped version of the string. For example `shiftString(“Hello World”, 3)` would produce
“rldHello Wo”.

I'm struggling to get it right

Thanks for your positive consideration towards my question.

Comment: Consider using `std::rotate`. By the way, what have you tried?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Comment: yes i did this is what i've tried:

Comment: string str;
while (true)
{
 str[] = str[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < str[i].length(); i++)
    {

     str[i] = str[i + 1];
        cout << str[i];
    }
    
}

Comment: @miltonaire Please edit the question instead of posting code in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Using the following produces the results you were looking for using a string, this could definitely use some refactoring. Sorry about that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string buffer("Hello World");
    basic_string <char> b2 = { 0 };

    const char arrsize = 3;
    char array2[arrsize] = { 0 };

    buffer._Copy_s(array2, arrsize, 3, buffer.length() - 3);
    b2.assign(array2, 0, 3);

    buffer.erase(8, 3);
    buffer.insert(0, b2);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`std::rotate`.
Don't reinvent the wheel.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/

Comment: Your *sample implementation* does not rotate, it simply overwrites characters at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Did you try running your code? You still have an off-by-one indexing bug. I don't understand why you mention `rotate` and then immediately proceed to handroll your own loop.